# How to join dataframes using a prefix as a match?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have those data:

```
data <- tibble(
  x = c("ANOTHER", "COMMON", "ZEBRA")
)
```

And I want to join this dataframe with this one:

EDIT: The prefix has no fixed length

```
selection <- tibble(
  x_prefix = c("A", "B", "CO"),
  type = c("One type", "Other type", "Other type")
)
```

I want to make an INNER JOIN with the `x` and `x_prefix` columns, with the idea that a line is kept if `x_prefix` is a prefix of `x`.

The expected answer is:

```
answer <- tibble(
  x = c("ANOTHER", "COMMON"),
  type = c("One type", "Other type")
)
```

How one can do that with dplyr?

Comment: `data` has no `type` column?

Comment: @Friede Nope!!!

Comment: I suspect, as you are looking for a `{tidyverse}` solution, you can borrow some code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67377408/20002111   Haven't testet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a `fuuzy_inner_join` with `str_detect` as the matching function. The symbol "^" is from regex, meaning start of a string, therefore we need to `paste` it to your pattern to only match strings starting with `x_prefix`.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

fuzzy_inner_join(data, selection, by = c("x" = "x_prefix"), 
                 match_fun = \(x, y) str_detect(x, paste0("^", y))) |> 
  select(-x_prefix)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x       type      
  <chr>   <chr>     
1 ANOTHER One type  
2 COMMON  Other type
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is to create a temporary `x_prefix` column and inner join on that

```r
data %>%
  mutate(x_prefix = substr(x, 1, 1)) %>%
  inner_join(selection, by = "x_prefix") %>%
  select(-x_prefix)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x       type      
#>   <chr>   <chr>     
#> 1 ANOTHER One type  
#> 2 COMMON  Other type
```

Comment: I will update the question, but the length of the prefix is not fixed

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution (but may be not that memory efficient due to `outer`)

```
> (d <- outer(data$x, selection$x_prefix, Vectorize(startsWith)))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE

> (idx <- rowSums(col(d) * d))
[1] 1 3 0

> cbind(data[idx > 0, ], selection[idx[idx > 0], "type"])
        x       type
1 ANOTHER   One type
2  COMMON Other type
```