# Is there a way to add a LIKE in a dbplyr inner_join SQL translation?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

This is a follow-up question to this one: [How to join dataframes using a prefix as a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78033008/6537892)

I have those two tables on a SQL server side:

```
data <- memdb_frame(
  x = c("ANOTHER", "COMMON", "ZEBRA")
)

selection <- memdb_frame(
  x_prefix = c("ANO", "B", "CO"),
  type = c("One type", "Other type", "Other type")
)
```

I want to join them and keep lines where the `x_prefix` is a prefix of `x`.

I am trying to build the appropriate SQL query with dbplyr, starting from here:

```
inner_join(data, selection, by = c(x = "x_prefix")) |>
  show_query()
```

which produces:

```
<SQL>
SELECT `x`, `type`
FROM `dbplyr_001` AS `LHS`
INNER JOIN `dbplyr_002` AS `RHS`
ON (`LHS`.`x` = `RHS`.`x_prefix`)
```

### The query I need is:

```
<SQL>
SELECT `x`, `type`
FROM `dbplyr_001` AS `LHS`
INNER JOIN `dbplyr_002` AS `RHS`
ON (`LHS`.`x` LIKE `RHS`.`x_prefix` || '%')
```

I have read that [Function translation vignette](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation-function.html) but I still need help.

Comment: As far as I can tell `dbplyr` follows [`dplyr::join_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) specifications, which doesn't support `%like%`. Perhaps it's an option to write this query manually via [`sql()`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sql.html), optionally with some string manipulation to make variable names dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to attempt this is using a cross-join and filter. I use this approach with dbplyr, because there is less flexibility for specifying joins in R than there is in SQL.

```r
# add placeholder column of ones to enable cross-join
data = data %>%
  mutate(ones = 1)
selection = selection %>%
  mutate(ones = 1)
# not necessary if there is another column you already intend to join by

cross_join = inner_join(data, selection, by = "ones") %>%
  select(-ones)

result = cross_join %>%
  filter(x_prefix == LEFT(x, nchar(x_prefix)))
```

I have used `LEFT` in capitals for it to be passed untranslated. There is a translation for `substr` but it would only accept numbers as inputs (and errored if I tried to use `nchar(x_prefix)` as the number of characters).

Another option for the filter would be to provide the condition as text within `sql()` to pass SQL code directly:

```r
result = cross_join %>%
  filter(sql("x LIKE x_prefix || '%'"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re already aware of the specific SQL query you need, it might be more efficient to execute it directly before returning to your dbplyr operations.

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
# Create a connection
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")


copy_to(con,tibble(
  x = c("ANOTHER", "COMMON", "ZEBRA")
),name="d1")

copy_to(con,tibble(
  x_prefix = c("ANO", "B", "CO"),
  type = c("One type", "Other type", "Other type")
),name="selection")
 
dbExecute(conn=con,
           statement = "create table result as
           select x, type from d1 as LHS 
              inner join selection as RHS
               on (LHS.x LIKE RHS.x_prefix || '%')")
 
 
my_res_dtplyr_table <- tbl(con,"result") 

#dtplyering with the result
my_res_dtplyr_table |> select(type) 
my_res_dtplyr_table |> filter(x != "COMMON")
```